# I want to get distance between my current location and multiple coordinates and then sort them

Tags: javascript, android, firebase-realtime-database, gps

I have multiple GPS coordinates in my firebase. I want to get the distance between them and my current location and then sort them in recycler view in the order of nearest to farthest.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I know how I can find the distance for a single coordinate. But I don't know how I can do that for multiple coordinates and then how to arrange them in order and show in recycler view.

Comment: So specifically, what did you try in code?

Comment: I didn't try anything yet. As I have very little knowledge in this location and GPS part.